# Is possible to add instructions

Tags: magento2

How can I create a toolbar like instructions through Displayed Error Message
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Magento 2 allows you to add tooltips and comments to your input fields. Please check the code below for reference.**

```
<field id="custom_url" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1" canRestore="1">
    <label>Url</label>
    <comment>You can add your instructions here</comment>
    <validate>required-entry</validate>
    <tooltip>You can add your instructions here</tooltip>
</field>
```

**OUTPUT:**
[image]

**Magento 2 enables the addition of dynamic comment messages to your input fields. Please refer to the code below for details.**

```
<field id="url" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="5" showInDefault="1" showInStore="1" showInWebsite="1" canRestore="1">
    <label>Url</label>
    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
    <comment><model>VendorName\ModuleName\Model\SystemConfigComment</model></comment>
</field>
```

**app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/Model**

**SystemConfigComment.php**

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Model;

use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;

class SystemConfigComment implements \Magento\Config\Model\Config\CommentInterface
{
    public function getCommentText($elementValue)
    {
        return 'You can add your instructions here';
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]